# French words ending in ...tion

Tags: vocabulaire

My teacher said that nearly all English words that end in ''tion'' came from French.

Therefore an English speaker already knows all these French words once they learn to pronounce the ''tion'' the correct way.

Are all English words ending in ''tion'' the same in French ?

If not what are the exceptions ?

How many of these ''tion'' words that have both an English and French version are there ?

Comment: La question est hors-sujet parce qu'elle repose sur un présupposé qui n'a pas été formellement établi et qui exige une connaissance d'une langue autre que le français pour y répondre. La question créé une confusion entre la langue anglaise et la langue française.

Comment: @ho2o2hh2o Quel est ce présupposé ?

Comment: @LPH On le trouve dans les phrases qui précèdent les questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, all English words ending in ''tion'' are not the same in French; there are exceptions as the "-tion" ending has been used with English stems and non English stems that are not French either. As a proportion of the whole English vocabulary ending in "-tion" there aren't many, but in itself the list is rather long.

1/ quite a few words issued from the creation of a noun by adding "tion" an English verb in "ize" (ise)

- weatherization, westernisation, winterization, digitalization, digitization, ghettoization (ghetto being perhaps of Italian origin and "ghettoization" being unknown in French), glamorization ("glamour" being from Latin origin and unknown in French),

2/  a few words issued from the creation of a noun by adding "-tion" to an English verb ending in "fy" (ise)

- beautification,  zombification,

3/ rare words issued from a pure English stem (or Irish or Scottish) and therefore that couldn't ever have been part of the French language.

- botheration, bowdlerization, spallation, gumption,

4/ words that you do not find in French because of a change in spelling.

- characterization (caractérisation), standardization (standardisation)
- The following forms, which are either a mainstream or a minority variant.
  connection ("x" rare), deflection ("x" rare), flection (rare), genuflection (not so rare),  inflection (mainstream), interconnection (mainstream, unique), irreflection (mainstream), reconnection (mainstream, almost unique), reflection  (mainstream, almost unique), retroflection (minority variant); all those forms take invariably x instead of "ct" in French. (suggested by user **[Laurent S](https://french.stackexchange.com/questions/40992/french-words-ending-in-tion/40994?noredirect=1#comment82593_40994)**)

5/ There are also those that appear to be French in reason of a French stem, but they do not exist in French.

- calculation (calcul), dictation,

6/ words with a Latin stem that has not been used in French

- implementation,

7/ words that appear to be French in reason of a French stem, but that do not exist in modern French

- impartation,

8/  words in the domain of the sciences which recently came into being in the Anglo-Saxon world and that are not necessarily used in French.

- spallation,

9/ words ending in "tion" to which have been appended  prefixes (mis, under, re…)

- misconception, misconnection,  misestimation, misevaluation, misfunction, misidentification, misinformation, misinterpretation, mislocation, misorientation, …
  underestimation, underinflation, undernutrition, underproduction, underrepresentation, …

10/ words with a different meaning

- vacation,

I can't find a study of this question, and therefore I have no precise numbers for the various categories of words that do not correspond on the count of at least one of the criteria (spelling, meaning, existence). The categories of words to watch for that I listed above are those I could make out from a quick study of the list of all English words ending in "-tion", a list that you can find [here](https://www.morewords.com/ends-with/tion) and study further in view of establishing a more detailed account of the situation.

Comment: Don't forget the infamous "connection" written "connexion" in French...

Comment: “Connexion” and “réflexion” are still intelligible especially if you read older literature with such spellings, but then there are meanings that may not be obvious: e.g. “partition” meaning a music score and not the English meaning of the word.

Comment: @Maroon I would't say "intelligible" but "still acceptable as a variant, albeit rare"; in particular for "connexion" it is the usual spelling when talking about a denomination in the methodist Church. This corroborates your remark on older literature: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=connexion%2Cconnection&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cconnexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconnection%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cconnexion%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cconnection%3B%2Cc0

Comment: @LaurentS. Connexion is accepted spelling in British English if I am not wrong

Answer (score 1):

I recognized that paying attention to the french words ending on "ion" is helpful to learn this wonderful language. You  may see that the following method works for most of this.

(Example)
fabrication -> fabriquer - la fabrique
information -> informer
formation -> former -> la forme

Another point: Have fun! Look for the special meanings IN a word. This will very often lead to its real or al least possible orign.

(Example)
maintenant --> main - tenant  : Hand holding  :-) And this refers normally to the present situation the speaker is in.

Answer (score 1):

Désolé pour l'attente. Comme le dit le mot "préambule", il y a une suite.
J'imagine que le but de la question est de savoir comment s'exprimer en français.
Ce préambule vise à rendre attentif au fait que ce qui prime, c'est le verbe, et pourquoi c'est le cas.

Sylvester a fait une remarque qui va dans le même sens. La première idée qui vient lorsqu'on voit des mots en "-tion" est le verbe qui y correspond.
Celui qui est allé sur le site de "reverso" a trouvé le lecteur de mots, ce qui répond à la question de savoir comment prononcer.

L'autre partie de la question est la relation avec le français.  Je ne dis rien au sujet des catégories, probablement exacte, mais de nombreux exemples y relatifs sont faux, à commencer par la liste de mots que les francophones ne comprendraient pas.

Même s'ils ne sont pas esthétiques, de nombreux mots sont compris, parfois repris, en particulier s'il n'y a aucun équivalent français et que ses composantes sont connues.
Évidemment que les digrammes sont décomposés en ajoutant des trémas " **¨** " sur les voyelles et que les accents sont parfois ajoutés.

La raison de ma réponse est que le message de LPH méritait commentaire.
J'en reprends la numérotation.

**1/** *quite a few words issued from the creation of a noun by adding "tion" an English verb in "ize" (ise)*

- Lorsqu'un mot comporte un *w*, il est pratiquement certain qu'il ne provient pas du français, Lorsqu'il contient un *wh*, il est certain qu'il ne provient pas du français.
- Le "z" est rare.

"-ize" est souvent la forme américaine de l'anglais "-ise"

.
* Ghetto est un quartier juif de Venise. Voici l'explication du (dictionnaire) Larousse.

https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ghetto/36870

"ghettoïsation" (évidemment, sans "z" )existe.
https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/ghetto%C3%AFsation/36871

- il est difficile d'échapper au mot "glamour", tant il est utilisé par les milieux de la mode et de l'art. Ce mot n'a pas été adopté par la population, entre autres parce qu'il décrit une vision du monde qui ne lui correspond pas.

**2/** *a few words issued from the creation of a noun by adding "-tion" to an English verb ending in "fy" (ise)
    beautification, zombification,*

Ces mots sont inconnus en français. la forme verbale "zombifier" serait possible.
"fy" correspond à une transformation, une mutation, une modification de la substance.

Mais on utilise plutôt un préfixe "a-", "en" etc  ( attention: Dans un tel cas, le "a" ne sert pas de privatif)
Exemple: a·noblir (rendre noble une personne) a le même sens que en·noblir (rendre noble une personne)

**3/** *rare words issued from a pure English stem (or Irrish or Scottish) and therefore that couldn't ever have been part of the french lnaguage.
    botheration, bowdlerization, spallation, gumption,*

C'est exact

**4/** *words that you do not find in French because of a change in spelling.
    characterization (caractérisation), standardization (standardisation)*

Pas tout à fait: "-iz" est la forme américanisée de l'anglais "is"
C'est en anglais qu'on ne trouve pas la forme "-iz"

En anglais, comme en français, le sens et l'orthographe sont pratiquement les mêmes: caractérisation, standardisation etc

**5/** *There are also those that appear to be French in reason of a French stem, but they do not exist in French.
    calculation (calcul), dictation,*

"calculation" n'est pas dans le dictionnaire mais est utilisé dans le domaine commercial, avec un sens différent de "calcul. Là aussi, on se crée un problème qui n'existe pas si on utilise le verbe "calculer".
Pour les mêmes raisons, on utilisera le verbe "dicter".

**6/** *words with a Latin stem that has not been used in French
    implementation,*

On utilise le mot "implémenter", en concurrence avec "mettre en place", "mettre en œuvre" etc C'est plutôt du jargon technique.

**7/** *words that appear to be French in reason of a French stem, but that do not exist in modern French
    impartation,*

Exact. En insistant sur le fait qu'il peut s'agir de mots d'ancien français, oubliés ou rarement usités.

**8/** *words in the domain of the sciences which recently came into being in the Anglo-Saxon world and that are not necessarily used in French.
    spallation,*

Oui, avec un bémol: Le jargon scientifique a un usage dans le domaine dans lequel il est pertinent d'en user.

**9/** *words ending in "tion" to which have been appended prefixes (mis, under, re…)
    misconception, misconnection, misestimation, misevaluation, misfunction, misidentification, misinformation, misinterpretation, mislocation, misorientation, …
    underestimation, underinflation, undernutrition, underproduction, underrepresentation, …*

Inexact dans le 1er cas; vrai dans le 2e.
Le 1er cas:
Le préfixe "mis-" existe, en concurrence avec "mé-", "més-"; "mal-" (séparé ou en tant que préfixe), "mau-", "mauvais"

"l'esprit" de la langue" n'aime pas les consonnes multiples. On comprendra, mais n'utilisera pas "misconception", "misconnexion". on adjoindra plutôt un qualificatif "mauvaise conception", "mauvaise connexion" etc, plutôt sous forme verbale: "c'est mal connectè"; "c'est mal conçu"etc

Voici ce qu'en français, les autres mots donnent: mésestimer; mal évaluer; mal identifier; mal informer; "misinterprétation" ou mésinterpréter seraient possibles, mais lourds - on utilisera "mauvaise interprétation"; "location" est un faux-ami (même mot, sens différent) - on utiliserait "localisation"; mauvaise orientation.

2e cas:
"under" correspond à "sous-" (avec trait d'union).

**10/** *words with a different meaning
    vacation,*
= Les faux-amis: location
, vacation etc

**Conclusion: Tout tourne autour de la manière de concevoir la phrase.**
* Il y a bel et bien beaucoup de mots d'origine française, même si ça ne se voit pas immédiatement.
* Là où l'anglais met un substantif, le français met un verbe, sans que pour autant le substantif manque en français.

- Ça diminue clairement la portée de la question: Le mot existe souvent, mais s'utilise sous forme verbale, ce qui économise 2 syllabes.
- Le traducteur prononce les mots entiers. le suffixe "-tion" se prononce toujours "-ksion" = "ksiõ"
  Le "on" est la forme nasale (le nez bouché) de la lettre "o". Phonétiquement, on l'écrit "õ"
  Voici à nouveau le lien vers le traducteur-énonciateur.
  http://www.reverso.net/text_translation.aspx?lang=FR

Comment: 1/ « C'est en anglais qu'on ne trouve pas la forme "-iz" »: cela est vrai pour l'anglais d'il y a quelque décades mais plus pour l'anglais contemporain; la forme en "s" n'est plus considérée que comme une variante secondaire. Pour se convaincre de cela, consulter le OALD : https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/us/definition/english/characterization?q=characterization 2/ « Inexact dans le 1er cas; » : strictement, ce n'est pas inexact, le préfixe « mis » n'existe pas en français. Il est cependant utile de noter la correspondance avec les autres préfixes.

Comment: @LPH *Il y a quelques **décades** ?* L'anglais n'évolue pas si vite...  quant à l'inexistence du préfixe *mis-*, le français a quand même misanthrope, misogyne et quelques autres même si ce *mis-* est peu productif et distinct du *mis-* anglais..

Comment: Lire « décennies » pour « décades » ci-dessus, « décade » n'est pas le mot  français pour « dix années », c'est le mot anglais..